# RoyalSlider : can’t access data attribut

Tags: jquery, plugins, royal-slider

I’m using the following wrapper for my RoyalSlider

```
<a class="rsContent white" href="#">
  <img class="rsImg" src="#" data-color="white" width="2560" height="1440">
</a>
```

I would like to check the value of the data-attribut for the first rsContent so i use the following code

`$('.rsContent').eq(0);` OR `$('.rsContent').first();`

which works fine so far but then when i try

`$('.rsContent').eq(0).data('color');` OR `$('.rsContent').eq(0).attr('class');`

Jquery returns

`undefined`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check The Log..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a class="rsContent white" href="#">
          <img class="rsImg" src="#" data-color="white" width="100" height="100">
        </a>
        <script>
            console.log($('.rsContent').first().attr("class")); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've checked the log: undefined

Comment: seems related to the royalsliderplugin because outside of royalsliders scope everything works fine.

Comment: Its means that your code works fine unless i add the royalsliderplugin.

Comment: It could be due to jq conflict. You might need to use: var jq = $.noConflict(); after importing the jq, then call it as $jq('.rsContent)..

Comment: i found an alternative by using data-color outside of rsContent. So it works. it seems that there is a conflict with my code and the RS plugin.